# How to make an aspx page do a httpredirect?

Tags: redirect, web-config

I'm trying to redirect an aspx page to another aspx page. But only as the aspx page get's called without any parameters.

So when it's called like this: https://www.a.com/test.aspx?param=1 it doesn't have to do anyhthing.
But when it's called like this: https://www.a.com/test.aspx it has to redirect.

I tried this, but it doesn't redirect, instead, it executes the aspx.

```
<system.webServer>
   <httpRedirect enabled="true" httpResponseStatus="Found" exactDestination="true">
      <add wildcard="*test.aspx" destination="/destination.aspx"/>
    </httpRedirect>
</system.webserver>
```

Any ideas?

extra info: it's from a https domain.

I also tried the following, but this makes it crash hard:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="myrule" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="/test.aspx" />
            <action
                type="Redirect"
                url="/destination.aspx"
                appendQueryString="false"
                redirectType="Found" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would using code in the page load of your ASPX page. If no querystring are provided, then do your redirect.

If you want to do the redirect earlier, you can also use the global.asax BeginRequest event to redirect (check the current request's URI and redirect if needed).

Comment: thx for the ideas, i eventually put it in the Onprerender method of the aspx file.

Comment: Prerender is late the page lifecycle. If you want to optimize the load time before your redirect, I advise you to do the redirect in the page PreInit or Init (check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(VS.100).aspx#additional_page_life_cycle_considerations) page for more information, the diagram is very useful).